# MySQL get last date and last id

Tags: mysql, max, group

I have data like this :

| id | trx_date | emp_id | amount | unit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 1000 | A |
| 2 | 2022-01-05 | 1 | 500 | A |
| 3 | 2022-01-02 | 1 | 2000 | A |
| 4 | 2022-01-02 | 2 | 1000 | A |
| 5 | 2022-01-31 | 3 | 500 | B |
| 6 | 2022-02-28 | 1 | 2000 | A |
| 7 | 2022-02-15 | 3 | 1500 | B |

And I need output like this :

| unit | year_month | amount_sum |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2022-01 | 1500 |
| B | 2022-01 | 500 |
| A | 2022-02 | 2000 |
| B | 2022-02 | 1500 |

Group by year_month + unit, then sum of amount on each employe with last date and max id (if more than 2 dates same)

Can you help me with correct query?

Comment: What queries have you tried so far? It would help if we could see them.

Answer (score 0):

On MySQL 8+, we can use `ROW_NUMBER` here:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DATE_FORMAT(trx_date, '%Y-%m'), unit, emp_id
                                 ORDER BY trx_date DESC, id DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT unit, DATE_FORMAT(trx_date, '%Y-%m') AS year_month, SUM(amount) AS amount_sum
FROM cte
WHERE rn = 1
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY 2, 1;
```